# How can I calculate global coordinates for GPencilStrokePoint in Blender 2.8 and Python?

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

I have already tried by calculating:

```
point_global_co = grease_pencil_object.matrix_world @ point.co
```

But it gives very odd results.

Answer (score 1):

The following script prints the global point coordinates for every grease pencil object in the scene. The coordinates seem to be accurate, judging from basic tests.

```
import bpy


for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == "GPENCIL":
        print(f"\n{obj.name}")
        for layer in obj.data.layers:
            for frame in layer.frames:
                for stroke in frame.strokes:
                    for point in stroke.points:
                        print(obj.matrix_world @ point.co)
```